# Creating field based on the sequential indicator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, sequential

I have a points layer in QGIS that is organised by time, with a column called `"Diff"` that has either `1` or `0`.

The `1` marks a point where there is a jump in time, the `0` marks where nothing has happened.

I want to create the column `"Group"` in Field Calculator where every time it sees a `1` it incrementally assigns a number, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4... as seen below:

| Diff | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This processing tool does exactly what you are looking for. Posted it as answer to a similar question I can not find anymore:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsField, QgsFeature, QgsProcessing, QgsExpression, QgsGeometry, QgsPoint, QgsFields, QgsWkbTypes,
                       QgsFeatureSink, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink, QgsProcessingParameterField, QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource, QgsProcessingParameterEnum, QgsProcessingParameterString, QgsProcessingParameterNumber)

class AddGroupByIndicator(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    SOURCE_LYR = 'SOURCE_LYR'
    ORDER_FIELD = 'ORDER_FIELD'
    TRIGGER_FIELD = 'TRIGGER_FIELD'
    GROUP_IDFIELD = 'GROUP_IDFIELD'
    INDICATOR_VALUE = 'INDICATOR_VALUE'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.SOURCE_LYR, self.tr('Source'))) # Take any source layer
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ORDER_FIELD, self.tr('Field the layer should be ordered by'),'Date','SOURCE_LYR'))
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.TRIGGER_FIELD, self.tr('Trigger Field indicating a new Group'),'Trigger','SOURCE_LYR')) # Choose the Trigger field of the source layer, default if exists is 'Trigger'
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                self.GROUP_IDFIELD, self.tr('Name of new generated GroupID Field'),'groupid')) # String of the new added fieldname, default is 'groupid'
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
                self.INDICATOR_VALUE, self.tr('Number indicating a new Group'),0,1)) # Indicator as number. 0=Int, 1 would be double; 1=default number
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT, self.tr('SourceWithGroupID'))) # Output

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        # Get Parameters and assign to variable to work with
        source_layer = self.parameterAsLayer(parameters, self.SOURCE_LYR, context)
        orderbyfield = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.ORDER_FIELD, context)
        triggerfield = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.TRIGGER_FIELD, context)
        groupfieldname = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.GROUP_IDFIELD, context)
        newlineindicator = self.parameterAsInt(parameters, self.INDICATOR_VALUE, context)
        
        groupid = 0 # initialize groupid counter
        
        total = 100.0 / source_layer.featureCount() if source_layer.featureCount() else 0 # Initialize progress for progressbar
        
        fields = source_layer.fields() # get all fields of the sourcelayer
        fields.append(QgsField(groupfieldname, QVariant.Int, len=20)) # add a new field to this list
        
        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context,
                                               fields, source_layer.wkbType(),
                                               source_layer.sourceCrs())
        
        # order the layer
        order_by_clause = QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause(orderbyfield, ascending=True)])
        feature_request = QgsFeatureRequest()
        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setOrderBy(order_by_clause)
        
        for current, feat in enumerate(source_layer.getFeatures(request)): # iterate over source 
            if feat[triggerfield] == newlineindicator: # if trigger appears increase groupcounter
                groupid += 1
            new_feat = QgsFeature(fields) # copy source fields + appended
            idx = 0 # reset attribute fieldindex
            for attr in feat.attributes(): # iterate over attributes of source layer for the current feature
                new_feat[idx] = attr # copy attribute values over to the new layer
                idx += 1 # increase fieldindex counter
            new_feat[groupfieldname] = groupid # assign the groupid
            new_feat.setGeometry(feat.geometry()) # copy over the geometry of the source feature
            
            sink.addFeature(new_feat, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert) # add feature to the output
            
            if feedback.isCanceled(): # Cancel algorithm if button is pressed
                break
            
            feedback.setProgress(int(current * total)) # Set Progress in Progressbar

        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id} # Return result of algorithm



    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return AddGroupByIndicator()

    def name(self):
        return 'AddGroupByIndicator'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Add group by indicator field')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('FROM GISSE')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'from_gisse'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr('This Algorithm adds a new group id found by a trigger')
```

How to use it:

1. Go to <kbd>View</kbd> -> <kbd>Panels</kbd> and Check <kbd>Processing Toolbox</kbd>
2. Now, in your <kbd>processing toolbox</kbd> click on the <kbd>python button</kbd> and choose <kbd>create new script</kbd>: [image]
3. Copy paste the code without any changes
4. Save it to the default folder (should be `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\`)
5. You can now find it in <kbd>Processing Toolbox</kbd> -> <kbd>Scripts</kbd> -> <kbd>From GISSE</kbd> -> <kbd>Add Group By Indicator Field</kbd>
6. Double click it and choose your settings, then hit <kbd>Run</kbd>

[image]

Example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Excuse my stupidity, but could you give me an example of this code as per my problem? I'm not sure how to implement this...

Comment: Thank you so much for such an in-depth answer, I really appreciate it! Works like a charm! Are there any other scripts from GISSE? Might be worth looking at their other stuff!

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers).

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query. Replace `myLayer` with your layer name. It will return a copy of all features in the original layer (with all attributes) and the computed group-sequence `"gp_seq"`.

```sql
SELECT *, sum(diff) over (ORDER BY id) as gp_seq
FROM myLayer;
```

Here is an example output (the field is `"gp"` instead of `"diff"` here)

[image]

Comment: That is why I am in love with a VL )